# Parent and Child fluent Linq query in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

*I've encountered a problem  in fluent LINQ for selecting a parent and a child into one `Ienumerable < anonymous type>`.*

For simplicity :

- There is a list of `commanders` (commander in each region).
- Each Commander has *its own*  `List of Soldiers`. ( and each `Soldier` has a bool property `IsCanWinWar` and a `Tool` which he uses to fight with)

I want to list ***each*** commander ( who has *one or more* solider *who can win the war*) *and* one `tool` name which is used by that soldier.

I dont care if a commander has more then one soldier who can win the war .

All a commander needs is a `tool` (*never-mind which tool*) from one of its soldiers (who can win the war).

the output is `Ienumerable < anonymous type>` where anonymous type is like :

```
{ 
  theCommander = [commanderObject] , 
  theToolName = [the tool name ]
}
```

*I did something with `selectMany` but it was very long and ugly.*

Is there any short query (**fluent query**) which can yield the same results in a shorter way?

```
public class Commander
    {
    public List<Soldier> lstSoldiers =new List<Soldier>(); //from db actually.
    }


    public class Soldier
    {
      public bool IsCanWinWar { get; set; }
      public string Tool { get; set; }
    }



void Main()
{
  List<Commander> lstCommanders = new List<Commander>(); //data source is actually from db.
  var MyIernumerableOfAnonymouseTypes= ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var MyIernumerableOfAnonymouseTypes = 
   lstCommanders.Select(c => new { 
                    theCommander = c, 
                    theToolName = c.lstSoldiers.Where(s => s.IsCanWinWar)
                                               .Select(s => s.Tool)
                                               .FirstOrDefault() })
                .Where(x => x.theToolName != null);
```

If there is no soldier which can win war, then tool will be null. Just filter out those commanders after selection.

BTW I think `Soldiers` is a better property name, then `lstSoldiers` (it has no prefix and it is PascalCase).

Comment: Yes you right(there's too much JS  in my life also , Sorry:-) ). But even so ,  I think `LstSoldiers` is better ( represents the structure itself.)

Comment: @RoyiNamir actually names should hide implementation details. You can use `IEnumerable<Soldier> Soldiers`. Or some other type of collection.

Comment: Ok I agree. :-). is there any solution with ANY ? cause its seems loic to find any commander who has any soldier who can win.... ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir you need solution with `Any` or solution which returns commanders and tools in fast way? :) Btw small notice - I believe all soldiers which can win should have not null tool?

Comment: Your solution is fine. But I just ask to expand my knowledge. cause if someone would have ask me how to do it , I would go with ANY. ( cause it seems logic :-) . But dont get me wrong. your solution is 100% fine. I just want to see  - if possible -  - how can / could I do it with ANY

Comment: correct. each soldier has a non-null tool. but not every tool can win the war.

Comment: @RoyiNamir then use yBee solution - filter commanders first, by verifying soldiers with ANY. Then select result

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25685/discussion-between-lazyberezovsky-and-royi-namir)

Answer (score 1):

First approach (revised later):

```
from commander in lstCommanders
where commander.lstSoldiers.Any(soldier => soldier.IsCanWinWar) // Consider only commanders who have at least one soldier who can win the war
select new
            {
                Commander = commander,
                Tool = (from soldier in commander.lstSoldiers
                        where soldier.IsCanWinWar // Consider tool originating from soldiers who can win the war
                        select soldier.Tool).FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

Second more concise and faster:

```
from commander in lstCommanders
where commander.lstSoldiers.Any(soldier => soldier.IsCanWinWar)
select new { Commander = commander, Tool = commander.lstSoldiers.First(soldier => soldier.IsCanWinWar).Tool };
```

In the fluent way:

```
lstCommanders.Where(commander => commander.lstSoldiers.Any(soldier => soldier.IsCanWinWar))
             .Select(  commander => new
                                         {
                                                 Commander = commander,
                                                 Tool = commander.lstSoldiers.First(soldier => soldier.IsCanWinWar).Tool
                                         });
```

Third option with one iteration:

```
from commander in lstCommanders
let winner = commander.lstSoldiers.FirstOrDefault(soldier => soldier.IsCanWinWar)
where null != winner // Consider only commanders who have at least one soldier who can win the war
select new { Commander = commander, Tool = winner.Tool };
```

Comment: That will enumerate each soldiers list two times.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky which solution will enumerate twice ? his first or second ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir both of them - it creates Any enumerator for filtering commanders, and enumerates each soldiers collection while there is any winner. Then it enumerates soldiers to get first winner from them

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I agree that first solution is not efficient. About the second I think that iterating twice through soldiers will not affect much the performance because _Any_ and _FirstOrDefault_ will stop when they found first matching soldier who can win the war. The third solution iterates through soldiers only once.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I made stop watch tests for several random commanders and soldiers. Your solution (best): 1189, my first: 1790, my second: 1763, my third: 2137. I don't know why third is the slowest one. I blame let clause.